# Allow range of ip in iptables

Tags: iptables

In my centos server I have vnc and I use firefox in Graphic mode
When I want to open private website for example : mywwebsite.web Firefox error me can not open site
But when I disable iptables with service iptable stop I can open mywebsite.web in Firefox
What is the problem and How I ca solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly this would be your answer.

Make sure to put in the proper IPs and ports

```
iptables -A INPUT -m iprange --src-range x.x.x.x-80 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT

iptables -A OUTPUT -m iprange --src-range x.x.x.x-80 -p tcp --dport 12345 -j ACCEPT

service iptables save    
service iptables stop
service iptables start
```

Also could you print your iptables if needed?

```
iptables -L -n -v
```